# Show that the equation $(1-x)\cos{x} = \sin{x}$ in $(0,1)$ has at least one solution.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, trigonometry, continuity

Show that the equation $(1-x)\cos{x} = \sin{x}$ in $(0,1)$ has at least one solution.

---

We have $f(x) = (1-x)\cos{x} - \sin{x} = 0$

We have
$$f(0) = (1-0)\cos{0} - \sin{0} = 1 - 0 = 1 > 0$$
$$f(1) = (1-1)\cos{1} - \sin{1} = 0 - \sin{1} = -\sin{1} < 0$$

So there must be a number $c \in (0,1): f(c) = 0$, so there is at least one solution.

---

Is this correct ? Did I forget or miss something ?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, in fact, I was looking for a fifth tag. I changed the tag. Thank you !

Comment: $f(x)$ is continuous and $0\lt \dfrac{\pi}{8}\lt\dfrac{\pi}{4}\lt1$ and $f(\frac{\pi}{8})\gt0$ and $f(\frac{\pi}{4})\lt0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine. Great job!.

A few remarks,

- I would first define $f(x)=(1-x)\cos x - \sin x$ and claim that the solution or the original equation is a root of $f(x)$.
- I would quote the intermediate value theorem explicitly and use the continuity of $f$.